# How to find KnowledgebaseId in Dialogflow?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

```
// const knowledgeBaseId = `the ID of your KnowledgeBase`;
```

I can't seem to find the knowledgebase ID in Dialogflow nor in the Cloud Console. Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird I my self couldn't find the **KnowledgeBaseId** even though I skimmed through dialogflow docs several times. But after several hours of searching I found a way that we could get it.

1. You should go to the the Knowledge base you created and right side there is chat window where you can test your chatbot response.
2. Type anything and you'll get a response card and below that there is an option called Diagnostic info.
3. Click it and you'll see the RAW API response and there you can see the **KnowledgeBaseId** inside it (it may be referred as source there). It should be in the format Format: `projects/<Project ID>/knowledgeBases/<Knowledge Base ID>`

[image]